# How do i go about finding the transfer function for this control system?

Tags: control-system

How do i go about finding the transfer function for this control system?
[image]

Comment: You do the right calculations that you should probably have learned for this homework...

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yes thank you. But This specific diagram is complicated to understand. Maybe you can simplify the diagram for me to understand.

Comment: Maybe you can point out the parts you understand and those you don't understand.

Comment: There are two general methods: (1) Introduction of state variables and succeeding mathematical manipulations or (2) block diagram manipulation (simplification).

Comment: @PlasmaHH So i know you can simply the first part into a parallel system of G and H but how does that link with the second part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fool-proof method is to create a system of equations describing your system and solve them for \$y/u\$ (the transfer function). Say \$v\$ is the left block output, and \$w\$ is the right block output. The system can be described by the following:

(1) :

$$
v = \frac{u-w}{1+T_1s}
$$

(2) :

$$
w = \frac{v}{T_2s}
$$

(3) :

$$
y = v + w
$$

Finding \$y\$ to \$u\$ relation should be simple from here.

Comment: Thank you but i already know this. Its just that for this specific diagram, i dont know how to find y/u

Comment: @Joe Substitute equation (2) in (1) and (3), then the resulting equation (1)' in (3)'. If you are stumped in alebraic manipulation, this should have been your original question.